# Some good reading on polygon algorithms

Tags: theory, computational-geometry

What are some good resources (books, articles, sites) about polygon intersection and union algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

My favourite site for real-world code examples has to be Dave Eberly's http://www.geometrictools.com, for books it has to be [Realtime Collision Detection](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/blog/) by Christer Ericson.

And although the information is sometimes hard to get at, the technical forums at [GameDev](http://www.gamedev.net/forum/12-graphics-programming-and-theory/) contain just about every computational geometry problem you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

1. The classic "Dutch" textbook is a good start:
   de Berg et al. "Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications"
   Chapters 2 and 3 are most relevant.
   http://www.cs.uu.nl/geobook/
2. Older textbooks also cover this topic quite well
   Preparata & Shamos "Computational Geometry: an Introduction"
   O'Rourke "Computational Geometry in C" (including code for basic operations)
3. Numerous online resources. Try the CGAL library for references and code.